# How to handle useContext when waiting for data to fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I am using useContext to fetch documents from MongoDB.

I know that there is some amount of time that it takes for my app to fetch the data, save it to state and then pass the context to children.

My question is - how do I handle the time inbetween fetching and rendering without having errors throw.

Here is some sample code where `projects` is the data coming from `useContext`:

PARENT

```
<Container>
    <div className={classes.cardsContainer}>
        {projects.length > 0 && projects.map((project) => <ProjectCard key={project._id}  project={project} />)}
    </div>
</Container>
```

I map over `projects` and pass each of these as a prop to `<ProjectCard />`.

However in the child if I try and render `project.projectName` (this is a property in the object) in the child.

If I `console.log(project.projectName)` in the children I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectName' of undefined`.

I know I can solve this by using `project && project.projectName` however is there a better way to do this?

There must be a more elegant way to do this so I don't have `object && object.property` everytime I want to use context.

Comment: [optional-chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)? You could also show a spinner while data is being fetched from the backend.

Comment: @Yousaf - are you able to optional-chain in a way so that you can use destructuring? I pass props into the component with destructuring so how would you approach that?

Comment: If you destructure an undefined property from an object, value of the destructured property name will be undefined, you won't get an error.

Comment: Howcome `project` is undefined? do projects contain null or undefined entities?
If yes, what about filtering? e.g. map(project => project ? <ProjectCard> : null)